# testing on python local host server leads me to directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, server, localhost

I need help understanding why my local host server comes up with a directory when i have all the appropriate files in my users/name folder.

I'm trying to test the local host using a simple bar chart from codepen but when I run the server, I just come across a directory listing but the links for the html,css and js are there. Is there something I'm missing in my folders or maybe a lost connection somewhere. My python knowledge is extremely basic so any help would be really appreciated

HTML

```
<div class="chart"></div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"  charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Code

```
var data = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42];

 var x = d3.scale.linear()
     .domain([0, d3.max(data)])
     .range([0, 420]);

d3.select(".chart")
   .selectAll("div")
    .data(data)
   .enter().append("div")
     .style("width", function(d) { return x(d) + "px"; })
     .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

CSS

```
.chart div {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  background-color: steelblue;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 1px;
  color: white;
}
```

CMD

```
C:\Users\name>python -m http.server
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 (http://0.0.0.0:8000/) ...
xxx.0.0.1 - - [09/Oct/2018 11:57:09] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
xxx.0.0.1 - - [09/Oct/2018 11:57:27] "GET /Java.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
xxx.0.0.1 - - [09/Oct/2018 11:57:35] "GET /css.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
```

Answer (score 1):

From the *Python 3* docs;

> do_GET() The request is mapped to a local file by interpreting the
>   request as a path relative to the current  working directory.
>
> If the request was mapped to a directory, the directory is checked for
>   a file named index.html or  index.htm (in that order). If found, the
>   file’s contents are returned; otherwise a directory  listing is
>   generated by calling the list_directory() method.

So because you do not have a *index.html* file (or any other file configured to act as the home page) the server lists the root directory contents instead. Simple solution would be to name your *html* file *index.html* and place it in the server's root directory and follow a step-by-step guide to setting up a simple Python web server such as [this](https://daanlenaerts.com/blog/2015/06/03/create-a-simple-http-server-with-python-3/). Hope that helps.